# How to see my downloaded image on media gallery?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-gallery

I have Xamarin.forms app. Some image arrives from Internet. I have button "Download". When I tap the button the image is saved on some Folder. But does not appear on Gallery.

This is code:

```
public class MediaService : IMediaService
{
    Context CurrentContext => CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;

    private readonly string path = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "Android", "data", "com.mob.drift", "files", "Pictures");

    public void SaveImageFromByte(byte[] imageByte, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            Java.IO.File storagePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(storagePath.ToString(), filename);
            var imagePath = path + "/Images";
            var imageFilePath = Path.Combine(imagePath, "img.jpg");



            //Check if the imageDirectory Exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(imagePath);
            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(imageFilePath, imageByte);
                MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Android.App.Application.Context, new string[] { imageFilePath, path }, null, null);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile does not scan the images. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I think you use the wrong path. You could use the code below and you could find the image fron the app folder.

MediaService:

```
Context CurrentContext => CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
    public void SaveImageFromByte(byte[] imageByte, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            var storagePath = Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
            string path = Path.Combine(storagePath.ToString(), filename);

            var imagePath = storagePath + "/Images";
            var imageFilePath = Path.Combine(imagePath, filename);

            //Check if the imageDirectory Exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(imagePath);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(imageFilePath, imageByte);
                MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Application.Context, new string[] { imageFilePath }, null, null);
            }
            else
            {
                //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(imageFilePath, imageByte);
                //MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Application.Context,  new string[] { imageFilePath }, new string[] { "image/png", "image/jpeg" }, null);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Download the image:

```
 static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public static Task<byte[]> DownloadImage(string imageUrl)
    {
        if (!imageUrl.Trim().StartsWith("https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            throw new Exception("iOS and Android Require Https");

        return _client.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl);
    }
```

Usage:

```
var BY = DownloadImage("https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3701/screenshots/5557667/xamarin-studio-1_2x_4x.png");

        var b = BY.Result;
        DependencyService.Get<IMediaService>().SaveImageFromByte(b, "img.jpg");
```

Check the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tba18.jpg

Comment: my code saved the image too. But main problem. Why when I open Android gallery I dont see the picture ? MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile  does not work.

Comment: What is the location of `Android gallery`? Have you check my screenshot? The code i provided works with MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile.